# How to find user_beancounters on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, kmemsize

I need to check kmemsize. How do I do it on ubuntu hardy server?

Update: I am using AWS/EC2/Scalr AMI 32 bit which is based on Ubuntu 8.04Hardy Heron with Fedora kernel. 
How can I can find kmemsize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/proc/user_beancounters` only exists if you are running under an OpenVZ kernel.

Comment: Why are you trying to find kmemsize? Again, you need to use a VZ kernel and it will be under /proc/user_beancounters. Maybe you should try to explain what you are trying to achieve, rather than what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

sybreon is correct.  However, if you are trying to check the kmemsize in a VPS, try the following and look for the kmemsize line:

```
cat /proc/user_beancounters
```

You may also want to ask your host if you are using ubc counters at all, if they have Virtuozzo (the commercial version of openvz) they may be using SLM, which allows you to set a flat memory limit in megabytes.